# In Scroll View Edit text has scroll both are worked but in edit text if we type no of lines user can't see edit text it is scroll to top.

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollview

In my layout i have scroll view in that scrollable edit text.Both are working by using `setOnTouchListener`.if we touch edittext it is scroll and layout scroll is interact.
But the **problem** is when user typing edittext it is moving top of the layout and user can't see edit text field.
**At the time user typing both scrolls are working.** 
i think solution will be when user is clicked on edit text we need to stop layout scroll.In that way edit text will visible to user and it is not moving when user typing.But i don't know how to implement it if anyone know please help me.

Layout code:-

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Welcome To Register Page"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/lin1"
        android:background="@drawable/shape">
     <TextView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Personal Details"
         android:gravity="center"/>
      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
          android:orientation="horizontal">
          <TextView
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="First Name :"/>
          <EditText
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/fname"
              android:inputType="textCapSentences"
              android:imeOptions="actionNext"
              android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
      </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Last Name :"/>
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/lname"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Phone No :"/>
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/pno"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/lin1"
        android:id="@+id/lin2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Address"
            android:gravity="center"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="City/Town :"/>
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/city"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="State :"/>
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/state"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Country :"/>
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/country"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Zip Code :"/>
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/zipcode"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lin3"
        android:layout_below="@id/lin2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Enter Full Address"
            android:gravity="center"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="10"
            android:lines="10"
            android:maxEms="1000"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:background="@drawable/shape"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lin4"
        android:layout_below="@id/lin3"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Other Details"
            android:gravity="center"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="E-Mail :"/>
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Date of Birth :"/>
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/dob"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:imeOptions="actionNone"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lin5"
        android:layout_below="@id/lin4"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Other Details"
            android:gravity="center"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="E-Mail :"/>
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/email_dum"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Date of Birth :"/>
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/dob_dum"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:imeOptions="actionNone"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lin6"
        android:layout_below="@id/lin5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Other Details"
            android:gravity="center"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="E-Mail :"/>
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/email_dum1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Date of Birth :"/>
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/dob_dum1"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:imeOptions="actionNone"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/lin6"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:id="@+id/submit"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/clear"
            android:text="Clear"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Main Activity_code:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText first_name,last_name,phone_no,city,state,country,zip_code,full_address,email,dob;

    Button submit,clear;
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;
    private Calendar cal;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        first_name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.fname);
        last_name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lname);
        phone_no=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pno);
        city=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.city);
        state=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.state);
        zip_code=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.zipcode);
        country=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.country);
        full_address=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.address);
        email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        dob=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.dob);

        submit=(Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        clear=(Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);

        cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);


        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,result.class);

                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("First_Name",first_name.getText().toString());
                bundle.putString("Last_Name",last_name.getText().toString());
                bundle.putString("Phone_No",phone_no.getText().toString());
                bundle.putString("City",city.getText().toString());
                bundle.putString("State",state.getText().toString());
                bundle.putString("Country",country.getText().toString());
                bundle.putString("Zip_Code",zip_code.getText().toString());
                bundle.putString("Full_Address",full_address.getText().toString());
                bundle.putString("Email",email.getText().toString());
                bundle.putString("DOb",dob.getText().toString() );

                intent.putExtras(bundle);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                first_name.setText("");
                last_name.setText("");
                phone_no.setText("");
                city.setText("");
                state.setText("");
                country.setText("");
                zip_code.setText("");
                full_address.setText("");
                email.setText("");
                dob.setText("");

            }
        });

        dob.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DateDialog();
            }
        });
        full_address.setOnTouchListener(new EditText.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getAction();
                switch (action) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        // Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                        break;
                }

                // Handle ListView touch events.
                v.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void DateDialog() {
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
            {

                dob.setText(dayOfMonth+"/"+monthOfYear+"/"+year);

            }};


        DatePickerDialog dpDialog=new DatePickerDialog(this, listener, year, month, day);
        dpDialog.show();
    }
}
```

u can check this code.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Linear Layout as a parent class instead of Relative Layout. so that the position of the edit text should get fixed by its weight and, it may be visible while typing.

Comment: problem is not in layout parent is scroll view.if enter more lines like 15 edit text is not visible to user. Because it is scrolled to top of the layout.